# ¿Por que llamamos al metodo setContentView() sin colocar objeto o clase por delante?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando comenzamos programando en Android en el Activity Main comenzaremos con el metodo On create de esta manera

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
.....
}
```

Pero al invocar el siguiente metodo

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Por que no se coloca alguna clase u objeto delante para llamar el metodo ? quizas es por que es el metodo es estatico, pero de que clase? y en que parte de la documentacion puedo saber si el metodo es estatico ?

Comment: normalmente en la programacion orientada a objeto, cuando escribes un codigo de esa forma esta implicita la palabra reservada <code>this</code> no es necesaria escribirla pero alli esta, el punto es que el objeto al que hace referencia <code>this</code> es a la propia clase en la que te encuentras, y 'setContentView' es una funcion de esa clase, no esta declarada en ninguna parte pero puedes acudir a ella igual porque la clase en la que escribes la hereda.

Answer (score 2):

> Por que no se coloca alguna clase u objeto delante para llamar el
>   metodo ? quizas es por que es el metodo es estatico, pero de que
>   clase? y en que parte de la documentacion puedo saber si el metodo es
>   estatico ?

No es necesario definir una clase ya que tu `Activity` extiende de otra clase ya sea `AppCompatActivity` o `Activity`,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

la cual ya contiene el método `setContentView()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que estas realizando en tu "Activity Main" es en realidad sobreescribir este método.

---

Esto es un concepto llamado  [**sobreescritura de métodos**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) u [**Overriding**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

`@Override` es utilizado para indicar al compilador la intención de sobreescribir un método de la clase padre.